# Entity Framework query - loading data optimization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

I'm using `FirstOrDefault` or `First` command in a query for retrieving data of an entity which has relation with other entities in my database.

My question is: do the `FirstOrDefault` or `First` command over a collection load all data of other entities associated with this entity into memory?

Comment: That depends on the O/RM pattern you use. [This might help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

The default behaviour of entity is lazy loading, so it won't load data until you ask for them.

Comment: One more think, you asked about the ram so you are curious about the performance, i think that for big db it is better to turn off this, i haven't checked the difference but imagine the situation.
You are looping through thousands of records, and checking one value from referenced tab.
So the lazy loading will send thousands of sqls for getting the referenced data. One per each loop.
You can manually load it when you are getting the data from the context and i bet that it will ask for data once. If i am wrong please write it.